# Toolbar doesn't show in Java GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, paint, jtoolbar

Why does the toolbar not show up? I want to put it under the File/help menu...Im recreating the paint application and I want to put the buttons on the toolbar. The menu works fine, I believe that the problem is that the canvas where the user draws is covering it but im not sure. Please help.

Comment: `contentPane.setLayout(null);` -- `<rant>`Why to folks continue to shoot themselves in the foot with such code, and then wonder why their GUI doesn't work?`</rant>` Seriously, don't do this.

Comment: I'm guessing you are recommending not to use the absolute layout? This is the only layout my professor wants us to use, and the only one he ever does demonstrations with. I removed it from the code and I still have the same problem...

Comment: @sdotriki, `This is the only layout my professor wants us to use,` - then your professor should be fired. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. The point is to let the layout manager do all the work determining size/location of components so you can concentrate on business logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
contentPane = new JPanel();
setContentPane(contentPane);
CustomCanvas panel = new CustomCanvas();
panel.setBounds(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
int xx, yy;
contentPane.add(panel);
contentPane.setLayout(null);

JToolBar toolBar = new JToolBar("This is the toolbar");
toolBar.setBounds(0, 0, 800, 50);
toolBar.setVisible(true);
```

The above code is a bit of a mess because you:

1. try to replace the content panel with a JPanel
2. then you try to use a null layout.
3. then you try to add components to the content pane

The end result is that the `CustomCanvas` is painting over the toolbar.

Don't do any of the above.

Instead let the layout manager of the content pane to all the work. The default layout for a JFrame is a BorderLayout. So typically you would simply use:

```
//contentPane.add(toolBar);
add(toolBar, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
```

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use ToolBars](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toolbar.html) for a working example to show you a better program structure.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I will definitely read that section you recommended! However, even with the add(toolBar, BorderLayout.PAGE_START); it still doesn't show up. :/

Comment: @sdotriki, You need to change the entire code to get rid of the null layout logic and setBounds() logic. That is why you need to START by reading the tutorial.